# Changing picture serveral times by click in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, click

I need a programm in HTML with javascript which has two pictures that by click changes from picture A to B and from picture B to A and so on. I think I need a loop...

Comment: Here is something to get you started. https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Following Code

```js
function changeImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    if (image.src.match("bulbon")) {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    } else {
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="pic_bulboff.gif" width="100" height="180">
<p>Click the light bulb to turn on/off the light.</p>
```

You Can Have example here https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_lightbulb

Answer (score 0):

you can find a good example of what you want to do in here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

you just need to tweak it a bit so it will change the images correctly.
I would recommend building a function with variables to store the images name.

```
<script>
   function ChangeImage(){
   var picElement1 = document.getElementById('HTMLImgElement1');
   var picElement2 = document.getElementById('HTMLImgElement2');
   var temp = picElement1.src;
   picElement1.src = picElement2.src;
   picElement2.src = temp;
}
</script>
```

In the html just set up 2 images with ID HTMLImgElement1 and HTMLImgElement2.
and a button with an onclick attr that will forward to this function.